# Trying to send FCM but sometimes it shows 400

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried to send FCM message with this JSON:

> {"data":{"before_end":"-941.813993","before_start":"341.813993","ended_at":"1480427700","id":"5","now":"1480426758","started_at":"1480427100","subtype":"in10","type":"chat_schedule"},"to":"/topics/13_notif","registration_ids":["ffM9IdvHBmY:APA91bF2LEUfxv_S8tmjfQccQR8VW_Yx9Zp25rrLbkIc9WnMeBh2tRfdMcDPsFqA6uqnIKFWLAygrVcr-98_krTikm8GeYC41kha-eoZ987HhPmbJNT7Eeo-UyHr7hJ6grS9PEm7q1ep","fgKJA8e2U_o:APA91bG09ZnKjNZxpnZmthmX5MR1A-hD3nepqCz0HesckF2HU6nS8MFJYbNX_OUH33ep6ZedN8UPy8AtSWQj4pkSrNTqPRb8pDGxhjSljpr-DvJ_7nwlAXc2SiNsV-XtNq4nfc8tZaqq","dlubMvP6e1k:APA91bEOmnkELD9HdlQMMPBm2KwWaiku7WpOixDzpAALr7VFO5sWQAkJjbYYphdLAV_4Hqlh8_9ixraebA3hn6I3CemLmqpnnR67jYq5fjtpTUqKldO6dtiZSMBZ6E9aZdwrrPxf_gUW","cKD8A2Rp2iw:APA91bF86nwk_SZIyVdymyiNgiTGlEr8YX4P44Hv7QXv6FcYyvswBV0mnYTbCEkj8dUAusPB8FXoC_9r0b9U1bNh7DScfUEHlF9KjHzynnwtyUmP0nCaWBBCW4CYn1YK01y_8uWAoPTJ","elN6OMhyhJ8:APA91bEQjALiSwtOzI84U9h5VgTji_pqBqF61K3By7-3u4cn_WQZSay9NkqXK4sSzj1wk6AsBhlD5wvQXmrddBn54mlAq5OeXA88fX0zGpx-nO6i2FtQ8OHyI8TwuASj2QrB7IFYkrxU"],"notification":{}}

but sometimes it shows 400 in the response struct:

```
    &fcm.FcmResponseStatus{
     Ok:            false,
     StatusCode:    400,
     MulticastId:   0,
     Success:       0,
     Fail:          0,
     Canonical_ids: 0,
     Results:       nil,
     MsgId:         0,
     Err:           "",
     RetryAfter:    "",
 }
```

After I google it for a while, 400 means:

> 400   Only applies for JSON requests. Indicates that the request could not be parsed as JSON, or it contained invalid fields (for instance, passing a string where a number was expected). The exact failure reason is described in the response and the problem should be addressed before the request can be retried.

For other json, it wasn't showing 400:

> {"data":{"before_end":"2613","before_start":"-4074","ended_at":"1480424100","id":"5","now":"1480426713","started_at":"1480422639","subtype":"in-1","type":"chat_schedule"},"to":"/topics/13_notif","notification":{}}

The response was:

```
&fcm.FcmResponseStatus{
    Ok:            true,
    StatusCode:    200,
    MulticastId:   0,
    Success:       0,
    Fail:          0,
    Canonical_ids: 0,
    Results:       nil,
    MsgId:         5721749585709774290,
    Err:           "",
    RetryAfter:    "",
}
```

What could possibly wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I shouldn't have use both `registration_ids` and `to` on the JSON.

On more detail `github.com/NaySoftware/go-fcm` may not be reused to send a broadcast topic then regids or vice versa, we must use different client or the `To` and `RegistrationIds` must be cleared first before can be reused.